# How to get multiple values with same key from an array PHP

Tags: php

I have an array where a key has multiple values. The key is the width of a product and the values are optional prices. The customer first chooses a width and than the options. How can I select the options from the array if a width is chosen? One of the first three columns is always chosen and then the other columns are optional. It should be possible to ad up the chosen values.

```php
$pricelist = [
    ["w70" => 573, 706, 895, 49, 270, 334, 65],
    ["w80" => 649, 801, 1017, 55, 307, 372, 65],
    ["w100" => 801, 990, 1260, 69, 384, 449, 76],
    ["w120" => 909, 1136, 1460, 81, 461, 525, 86],
];
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the how it is chosen? Are you talking API endpoint, form data,...?

Comment: The values are chosen in a HTML form using the post method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want get array data with specific keys first you need change your array structure to

```
$pricelist = [
        "w70" => [573, 706, 895, 49, 270, 334, 65],
        "w80" => [649, 801, 1017, 55, 307, 372, 65],
        "w100" => [801, 990, 1260, 69, 384, 449, 76],
        "w120" => [909, 1136, 1460, 81, 461, 525, 86],
    ];
```

and than you can get data with specific key , example

```
$pricelist['w70'];
```

Comment: Sorry, It still is not clear to me, say i have a variable $width = "w70"  and a variable $height = "17cm" which stands for the second column. Then how can i retrieve the number 706 from this example.

Comment: The problems looks like that nobody knows that `17cm` = `706`. What you might need is `"w70" => ['10cm' => 573, '17cm' => 706, '20cm' => 895, ...],`. Now you can use `$pricelist['w70']['17cm']`

Comment: I am a newby, can i use $pricelist[$width][$height] instead of $pricelist['w70']['17cm'], and if not how do i convert it? And how do you make the grey fields?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using a $$ variable variable. Maybe it is a bit strange but it works. I used $$baseprice = $pricelist[$width][$height]. This enables me to get any key value pair from the array. For example $width = "w70" and $height = 1, this returns 706. If there is a better way, please share. I thought i was wrong but i was mistaken. This is not the best solution.The first answer is what i was looking for after all.

Comment: You answer is in essence another question. Maybe change your question to the question in your 'self-answer', since this is not marked as accepted answer.